# need bash script to strip version in a binary file and compare to db version

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

trying to setup a bash script to look for the version in a binary file all the versions are included so I am thinking I have to strip out the `AUDIT_TRAIL_#_##_A-Z,1-9`

This is what I have so far any suggestions

```
#!/bin/bash
echo searching fmx files AUDIT_TRAIL FOR FORM VERSION
for file in `/bin/ls *.fmx`
do
  current_release=`strings $file |sed "s/\"AUDIT_TRAIL/NOTNEEDED/" |grep -i "AUDIT_TRAIL_8" |sed "s/AUDIT\_TRAIL\_/AUDIT\-TRAIL /" |sed "s/\_/\./g" |sed "s/\.[A-Z,a-z]/\.00/" |awk '{print substr($0,0,18)}' |awk '{print $2}'`
  export form=$(echo "$file" | cut -f1 -d'.')
  export dbform=`echo $form |awk '{print toupper($0)}'`
  echo "FORMNAME" $form
  sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect system/xxx@xxxxx
set echo on
whenever oserror  exit 88
whenever sqlerror exit 1
spool forms.lst
select GURAOBJ_CURRENT_VERSION from bansecr.GURAOBJ where GURAOBJ_OBJECT = '$dbform';
spool off
exit
EOF
  echo $file $current_release
done
```

OUTPUT

```
bash-4.1$ ./find_current_release_fmx_db.shl                                                                                                                                                             
+ ./find_current_release_fmx_db.shl
./find_current_release_fmx_db.shl: line 1: !/bin/bash: No such file or directory
searching fmx files AUDIT_TRAIL FOR FORM VERSION
FORMNAME peaempl
```

**FROM THE DATABASE**

```
GURAOBJ_CU
----------
8.11.2
```

peaempl.fmx

**FROM THE COMPILED FORM**

```
8.0 8.0 8.0.00 8.0.00 8.1.0. 8.1.0. 8.2.00 8.2.00 8.3 8.3 8.4 8.4 8.7.1 8.7.1 8.7.1. 8.7.1. 8.8.0. 8.8.0. 8.8.1. 8.8.1.  **THE ONE I NEED 8.11.2**    8.11.2 8.1.0. 8.8.0. 8.7.1. 8.11.2 8.0.00 8.2.00 8.0 8.3 8.4 8.8.1. 8.7.1
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

**8.11.2**

***Any help would be greatly appreciated***

Comment: I attempted to edit this for formatting but couldn't tell which bits were actual code, which were output and which were comments. Please use the code formatting (`{}`) button for blocks of code and literal output.

Comment: I tried the best I could. The error message suggests that there's a `#!!/bin/bash` shebang at the top of the script instead of `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thank you this is my first time posting here I will look it ( editing-help.)  over

Comment: I need to edit my post

Comment: Also better to user parentheses compare to old backtics, its more readable.  Also quote variable to keep formatting of the data. `export form=$(echo "$file" | cut -f1 -d'.')`

Comment: What is your question? Your subject sounds like you're asking how to extract a string from a binary file, but then you show a lengthy shell script doing all sorts of crazy pipelines and unnecessary commands and then post some text under `FROM THE DATABASE` and other text `FROM THE COMPLIED FORM` that have absolutely no relation to each other or to anything above those lines as far as I can tell. Please put some thought into how to phrase the specific question you have and including information that helps clarify rather than obfuscate the question and then edit your question to start over.

Comment: It looks like maybe what we need to see as a starting point is some sample output of `strings <somefile>.fmx` (since it looks like that will be the input to whatever command we help you come up with) and the final expected output from the command you want given that `strings` output as input to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by tidying up your script to not use so many pipes and commands, to be more robust, etc.:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'searching fmx files AUDIT_TRAIL FOR FORM VERSION\n'
for file in *.fmx
do
  current_release=$(strings "$file" | awk '<something>')
  form="${file%%.}"
  dbform="${form^^}"
  printf 'FORMNAME %s\n' "$form"
  sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect system/xxx@xxxxx
set echo on
whenever oserror  exit 88
whenever sqlerror exit 1
spool forms.lst
select GURAOBJ_CURRENT_VERSION from bansecr.GURAOBJ where GURAOBJ_OBJECT = '$dbform';
spool off
exit
EOF
  printf '%s %s\n' "$file" "$current_release"
done
```

Now all we need to know is what the `<something>` in the awk command should be. I couldn't figure it out from your chain of piped commands as they seem to be adding stuff and then removing it again and escaping things that shouldn't need to be escaped, etc. but once you show the sample output of `strings` and what you want the awk script to convert that into it should be obvious.